# Receiving an error on the Initial Seed for the Users collection

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm getting an error when it goes to create the initial seed. I'm not sure why, I'm able to seed the role collection with no problem. I'm kinda just following what was done for that one. But I'm thinking because of the relation to the role array, I need to write the initial seed differently for the users collection. Can someone take a look at the code I supplied and see if they can help me out?

The error:

```
error Error: User validation failed: roles.0: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "user" at path "roles", roles: Cast to Array failed for value "[ 'user', 'mod', 'admin' ]" at path "roles"
```

Initial Seed:

```
if (!err && count === 0) {
  new User({
    username: "admin",
    email: "admin@sumemail.com",
    password: "123456",
    roles: ["user", "mod", "admin"]
  }).save(err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error", err);
    }
    console.log("added 'admin' to users collection");
  });
}
```

User Schema:

```
const User = mongoose.model(
  "User",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    userid: String,
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    roles: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Role"
      }
    ]
  })
);
```

Role Schema:

```
const Role = mongoose.model(
  "Role",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing string(name) instead of object Ids of role collection.

```
let role_ids = ["5ef63f92e2ad860554ad5472", "5ef709f7233a9b5cd2f89022"]


if (!err && count === 0) {
  new User({
    username: "admin",
    email: "admin@sumemail.com",
    password: "123456",
    roles: role_ids
  }).save(err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error", err);
    }
    console.log("added 'admin' to users collection");
  });
}
```

if you specify roles as mongoose object id. mongoose validation tries to validate your data as mongodb object id.